# Strategy to reset a GitHub-repository while developing

Tags: git, github

I'm currently working on software-project. Just me by myself with no team involved.

I use GitHub for to backup my code. When I decide to end the day I push my local repository to GitHub. So I have always an online backup of my project.

That works fine so far. But sometimes it can happen that I start to work in the morning and after a few hours I discover that I have made some mistake which damages the whole thing. So I want to restore my local copy to the state of the last server-copy.

What's the most elegant way to accomplish these operation.

Friends told me about the concept of master and forks.

Shall I use that?

In case of yes: What are the concrete terminal commands?

Comment: It sounds like you have no idea what git is for. Start here: http://gitimmersion.com/

Comment: @Chris Kitching I don't mind. I use it as described and it works well => Provides what I want to have (a backup which I can access from everywhere).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [branching](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging). I recommend you to read this [post](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) about development model.